# Unable to update two tables with php at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an asignment: create a college database with two tables...

- Table #1 = `Students_info`
- Table #2 = `teachers_info`

`students_info` has columns name, class, and teacher_id, and `teachers_info` has Id, t_name...

The result on browser showing columns...

```
Student name, teacher name, class....
```

with three buttons: Edit, Delete and Add new for every record...

My questions is how can I edit, delete, or add new record in both tables from php?

To understand my question please see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is not the kind of question allowed on Stack Overflow, we're not here to do something else's work.  What you should do is try to do it yourself and if you have any problem doing so, then post it and we'll try to help you, but first of all you should demonstrate that you put some effort yourself.

Comment: I am fresh student of php...
I have done it one table but in two tables i have tried my best but faild...

Answer (score 1):

Its just simple.When you click edit,just fetch the values from the textboxes and on submitting update the respective columns  of respective tables in database.